# syntax error in expression (error token is "1") bash script

Tags: lvm

I am getting a syntax error when I try to test the following and it appears to be due to the 0 which is there.   What am I missing here?

This is the code:

```
echo =========================================
echo sum of 4 arguments:"$requestedsum"
if [ -n "$requestedsum" ]
then 
(( $(echo "$requestedsum > $vg_free_space" |bc)));
echo "Requested space is not available in VG";
else
echo "Requested space is available";
fi


=========================================
sum of 4 arguments:0
10
./sizecheck.sh: line 26: ((: 0
1: syntax error in expression (error token is "1")
Requested space is not available in VG
```

Comment: can you share the entire part of the script that's relevant?

Comment: `(( ... ))` is a conditional, what do you want that line to do?

Comment: @BenjaminW,  I am trying to compare requestedsum with the existing space numbers.

Comment: @mmenschig,  I have pasted the bash -x output via external link.  I couldn't post it here as site was asking me to put words to finish my edit.  Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: And what's the result of the comparison? Do you want to use it in a conditional? Your code uses the conditional as a command. Can you describe what should happen for each possible outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I see:
requestedsum='0
10'

Seems not to be a simple value. Try to assign a simple value to requestedsum.

Comment: Not sure from where that "0" is coming as sum is basically a $1+$2+$3+4.